# [ERROR]: Visual Studio 2017: Unable to start program "http://localhost:xxxxx/". Operation timed out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

[image]I am trying to create a new `ASP.NET MVC` project in `Microsoft Visual Studio 2017`. I get the following error when I run the project immediately after `Visual Studio` has finished setting it up for me:

> Visual Studio 2017: Unable to start program "http://localhost:xxxxx/". Operation timed out.

I have not made ANY changes to the project. I am unable to run the project. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon running the project for the first time, I was getting the above mentioned error. Then, after closing and reopening the project, I got a different error:

> Visual Studio 2017 error: Unable to start program, An operation is not legal in the current state.

For the above error, I found the solution in the following link: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692472/visual-studio-2017-error-unable-to-start-program-an-operation-is-not-legal-in)

After following the steps mentioned in the correct answer in the link, I could solve the issue. The project is working fine now.